# How can I accept a Rust HashMap with any hashing algorithm?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'm working on a library that has a function that I would like to be able to accept a HashMap of any hashing algorithm. But when I try to call it with a particular type of HashMap, such as a FnvHashMap, the compiler complains.

```
pub fn func(map: HashMap<u32, u32>) {}

let map: FnvHashMap<u32, u32> = FnvHashMap::default();
func(map);
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> lib.rs:42:10
   |
42 |     func(map);
   |          ^^^ expected struct `RandomState`, found struct `BuildHasherDefault`
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<_, _, RandomState>`
              found struct `HashMap<_, _, BuildHasherDefault<FnvHasher>>`
```

As [FnvHashMap](https://doc.servo.org/fnv/type.FnvHashMap.html) is only a type alias I thought this wouldn't be a problem.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I haven't found it yet. What's the correct way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `HashMap` [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) is:

```
pub struct HashMap<K, V, S = RandomState> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

`RandomState` is the default type, but it can be overridden with another type, including a generic. It may not be immediately clear, but most of the `HashMap` methods are declared in [an `impl` block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html?search=#impl-2) that constraints `S: BuildHasher`, which is the trait you need to bound it by:

```
use std::hash::BuildHasher;

pub fn func<S: BuildHasher>(map: HashMap<u32, u32, S>) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense, and it matches the function definitions I've seen elsewhere.